# Preloading another webpage from the current webpage

Tags: jquery, html, web, preload

I have been looking for this for a while, and I only find articles and threads about loading webpages using an overlay or a loading bar. Currently I am using the queryloader2 to load my webpage (which uses a loading bar):

http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

However, I would like the loading of this webpage to occur in the background. Here is what I imagine:

Someone comes to my website (and lands at 'page 1'), and they're having a look around, and then click a link (to 'page 2'). I would like the user to be redirected instantly to 'page 2' without the need to stare at a loading bar. For this to occur I would therefore like the page to load in the background while they browse 'page 1'.

The closest match I have found is this (however I can't get it to work and don't have enough reputation to comment)
[Preload image in index.html to use on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870875/preload-image-in-index-html-to-use-on-another-page)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Paul

Comment: Refer to HTML5 tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830675/how-can-i-preload-a-page-using-html5

Comment: Thanks! I knew it'd be simple, just didn't really know what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Question Answered (created my own answer in attempt to close the question). See the comment from Alexander:

> Refer to HTML5 tags:
>   [How can I preload a page using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830675/how-can-i-preload-a-page-using-html5)